# How to solve 'DRIVER_UNLOADED_WITHOUT_CANCELLING_PENDING_OPERATIONS' caused by intelppm.sys?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox

I use virtualbox to install xp.

When I boot, it shows:

[image]

And I can boot into safe mode.

Comment: read this and say whether it can be appiled to you i googled and found this for intellppm.sys http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/blue-screen-it-says-intelppmsys/e614cd4c-8111-463a-9e53-9c5868f008e3 and please crop the image and post it

Comment: Adding a +1 for this even though my BSOD referenced P3.sys.  I followed the "if that doesn't work" steps on the accepted answer below, substituting P3.sys for intelppm.sys and I'm all set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `DRIVER_UNLOADED_WITHOUT_CANCELLING_PENDING_OPERATIONS` bug check has a value of `0x000000CE`. This indicates that a driver failed to cancel pending operations before unloading.

More details and fixes here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you are seeing this problem repeatedly you can manually disable these drivers (with no negative side effect) by going to the following location in the registry:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Processor` and changing the `Start` value to '4'. 
Or
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Intelppm` and changing the `Start` value to '4'.

If that doesn't work then try to:

1. Boot in Safe Mode + Networking (F8 at startup)
2. Go to %Systemroot%\Inf\ and delete all OEM#.inf
3. Search for intelppm.sys in the c:\windows\ (search for hidden directories and system files) - Delete the 3 results of intelppm.sys
4. Reboot the Guest normally

The suggestion above (and more) is from [VirtualBox forum](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/420)

**HOWEVER**, your issue may not be due to the Virtual Box as it mentions the `intelppm.sys`

So, if the above doesn't work, try

1. Boot in Safe Mode + Networking (F8 at startup)
2. Delete the files intelppm.* existing in the c:\windows\ and sub-dirs.
3. Go to %Systemroot%\Inf\ and delete all OEM*.inf
4. Re-install Guest Additions.
5. Reboot

Comment: I change regedit by your method,and it works! Thank you~

Comment: I have to wait for 2 minute...by the rule of this board.

Comment: What happened when I disable intelppm.sys? What function I will loss? Thank you~

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but you can always re-install the drivers. For example, you can download the drivers from the Intel website depending the Network Adapter you choose; if you need 100Mbps choose PCnet-FAST III, as it should not give such problem as you're experienced. However, if it works for you now, I would leave it as is.

Comment: How do I know which driver depend on intelppm.sys? Thank you~

Comment: You can run listsvc to see the list of all services and drivers. I'm not sure if this answer you though but it may help

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the BSOD text, the problem originates from `intelppm.sys`. This is one of the available CPU drivers that Windows XP ships. I hit this issue when converting a Virtual Box disk image to QEMU. In my case, the file `processr.sys` was mentioned instead.

Symptoms:

- Initially the image boots, but you get a BSOD (`DRIVER_UNLOADED_WITHOUT_CANCELLING_PENDING_OPERATIONS`) on shutdown.
- You get a BSOD (with the above text) on boot.

Solution(s):

- Disable the `processor` and/ or `intelppm` services as demonstrated by Dave Rook. (Go to `HKLM\System\ControlSet001\Services\<service name>` and change `Start` to `4` to disable the service completely.)
- Prevent installation of these drivers in the first place by removing `C:\Windows\inf\cpu.inf`.

Extra information:

- The drivers probably provides functionality like CPU scaling which are likely not supported by these virtualization platforms. You won't notice any missing functionality.

If you are looking for a way to prepare an image for QEMU, have a look at this tool:
https://github.com/Lekensteyn/qemu-tools/blob/master/vbox-to-qemu.py