# Windows XP virtual machine in VirtualBox fails to boot after disabling VT-x/AMD-V

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, hardware-virtualization

I use VirtualBox 4.3.4 and I want to move a Windows XP base VM from my PC to my laptop.

I have a 64-bit Windows 8 on on my PC so VirtualBox supports CPU acceleration and hardware virtualization. But my laptop has a 32-bit Windows XP and so its VirtualBox doesn’t have support for CPU acceleration and hardware virtualization.

When I move virtual hard disk from My PC to laptop, the Windows XP in my VM load to welcome screen and so reset due to a system failure.

I am find that the cause is in “Acceleration -> Hardware Virtualization.” So in My PC when I uncheck the “Enable VT-x/AMD-V” In “VirtualBox -> Machine -> Settings -> System -> Acceleration -> Hardware Virtualization” then my VM failed to load.

In this state if I try safe mode, Windows XP can load without error but in normal mode it failed.

What I do?

Comment: What exactly is the error message that you see when Win XP fails to load in the VM?

Comment: No Message appear! Only Restart suddenly.

Comment: In Safe Mode, use `msconfig` to [set the `BOOTLOG` and `SOS` boot options](http://delltech.150m.com/XP/wininst/12.htm) and restart the OS and see if you get any error messages.

Comment: No. Last message was: "Windows has finished checking the disk", then the blue "Welcome Screen" appear for a moment, and then restarting!

Comment: I'm not really sure what the cause of the problem might be. Maybe uninstalling VirtualBox Guest Additions might help?

Comment: Oh! I uninstalled VirtualBox Guest Additions so a new big error message in an dark blue screen appear that say: *" **intelppm.sys** file caused the error: DRIVER_UNLOADED_WITHOUT_CANCELLING_PENDING_OPERATIONS"*. and it say: *"Disable or remove any newly installed hardware or software. Disable BIOS memory option such as caching or shadowing"*.

Comment: [This might help](http://superuser.com/a/460947/167187). Also try logging into the recovery console and run the command `disable intelppm.sys`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve 'DRIVER\_UNLOADED\_WITHOUT\_CANCELLING\_PENDING\_OPERATIONS' caused by intelppm.sys?](https://superuser.com/questions/460946/how-to-solve-driver-unloaded-without-cancelling-pending-operations-caused-by-i)

Answer (score 0):

The reson is disabling Hardware Virtualization **VT-x/AMD-V** in fact is such that you replace your CPU with another one and cause change hardware. So old CPU driver conflict by new CPU hardware.

This problem discussed and answered in:

[How to solve 'DRIVER_UNLOADED_WITHOUT_CANCELLING_PENDING_OPERATIONS' caused by intelppm.sys?](https://superuser.com/q/460946/364333)

In this case the problem solve by only changing the below registry value:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Processor` and changing the `Start` value to `4`.
Or
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Intelppm` and changing the `Start` value to `4`.

For this you need to use safe mode. Restart your virtual machine, press F8 to select advanced startup options and then select safe mode. After loading Windows press **Start** button and then click "**Run...**", type the **regedit** and follow above registry location and change value of `Start` to `4`. Then restart VM. It must work!